# Image Viewer Ctrl+C not copying image correctly sometimes

Tags: shortcut-keys, image-viewers

I'm preparing a Google Slides presentation on Ubuntu 20.04, and it involves copying and pasting a lot of png images. Typically I'd like to just open a PNG file with something like Image Viewer, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the image, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close it, and then in Google Slides <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste the image.

However, when I do this, about 50% of the time it pastes the image file's path as text, instead of pasting the actual image.

Is there a way to ensure that I consistently copy the image each time (ideally without relying on the mouse)? It's starting to get annoying.